# Can I uninstall linux-image-generic-lts-vivid?

Tags: apt, kernel

I'm having major problems in a server because of this package. I'm not being able to install nor update any packages because of this message:

```
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Você pode querer executar 'apt-get -f install' para corrigí-los.
Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:
 linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid : Depende: linux-headers-3.19.0-66-generic mas não está instalado
 linux-image-generic-lts-vivid : Depende: linux-image-3.19.0-66-generic mas não está instalado
                                 Depende: linux-image-extra-3.19.0-66-generic mas não está instalado
                                 Recomenda: thermald mas não está instalado
E: Dependências desencontradas. Tente usar -f.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only *can* you uninstall this package, you *should* uninstall it, as the Vivid (15.04) HWE for Trusty reached its end of life in August 2016.

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

If you need a kernel newer than the 3.13 provided in Trusty, you can install a 4.4 kernel with the Xenial HWE as described in the above page

Comment: But will I have to do anything other than uninstall it? Or, just an apt-get purge will do the job and no more headache?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Just for notice, this is my Ubuntu version:

`Linux lvrjdev2 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`